# How to get all contents in a json file sent to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have test results that are being stored in json files. I then have logstash locate the file and attempt to send all of the lines to elasticsearch. Only about half of the lines are being sent and can't figure out why certain lines are being left out. For example, there will be 34 lines, but only 14 are sent.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/data/*.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

filter {

    # Parse fields out of JSON message, then remove the raw JSON. 
    json {
        source => "message"
    }

}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["host:9200", "localhost:9200"]
        index => "ct-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

I'm not sure if there is something within the json itself that causes logstash to just skip over it, or if there's something wrong with my logstash.conf file that I posted above.

Comment: Here is what I think is happening. I thought by having two elasticsearch hosts that I could send the json logs to both. It seems like it's splitting the json results and sending some to one host and the rest to the other host. Is that how it works? Is there a way to bypass and send everything to both locations or do I have to change the output to only have one location?

Comment: All events will be sent to all outputs, so that's not the cause.

Comment: Have you seen the json codec that you could on the input?  That should save the filter.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html

Comment: @Patrick please share contents of your JSON file.

Comment: @AlainCollins According to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts), it's not the case: `If given an array it will load balance requests across the hosts specified in the hosts parameter.`

Comment: @Patrick if you want to send the same logs to two elasticsearch hosts which are not part of the same cluster, you'll have to use two elasticsearch output, each with one host

Comment: @baudsp - I read it too fast.  It will be sent to all outputs (ES and stdout in OP's example), but how each output handles it can be different.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash computes files from different types to send it to elasticsearch in Json format. In your case, a Filebeat agent with an elasticsearch output would be enough to send a json file to ES and to index it.

It would look like this using Filebeat 6.x :

```
#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  # Paths to the logs
  paths:
    - "/your/path/to/your/logs/file.json"
  # tags to identify the logs source, .gz files excluded from the prospector
  tags: ["beats","yourtag"]
  exclude_files: ['\.gz$']

#================================ Outputs =====================================
#----------------------------- Elasticsearch output --------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # The ES host & index name
  hosts: ["yourEShost:9200"]
  index: "ct-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```